# Error loading data in MariaDB Columnstore

Tags: mariadb, columnstore

I have a MariaDB Columnstore database running on the cloud in Linux. I'm trying to export a CSV file from my Windows machine to the database. I created the file with DBeaver, setting the new line as `\n`. I execute the `cpimport` command (provided by MariaDB) and I get the following error:

```
line 2: $'\r': command not found
```

I cannot figure out where's the problem, is it in the CSV file or in the `cpimport`?

This is how I import in MariaDB:

```
sudo cpimport -s '|' -E '"' -C '\n' my_database dates dates.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the mariaDb documentation of cpimport https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/col/cli/cpimport/, We need to specify the field delimiter with the -s option. If you are using a CSV file then you should specify field delimeter option as -s ',' but I see in your command its -s '|' which is for pipe separated values.